# Why Java 9 does not simply turn all JARs on the class path into automatic modules?

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

In order to understand the categories we have:

- platform explicit modules
- application explicit modules
- <s>open modules</s>
- automatic modules
- unnamed module

All classes and jars within the classpath will be part of the unnamed module. But why is that what we need? Where is the advantage over automatic modules? I could "require" those damn legacy jars to make them to an automatic module. Do I not have included everything with it?

Comment: Listing open modules in that enumeration is a little weird because they are included in "application explicit modules".

Comment: Can somebody that understands this question please edit it to use proper grammar in the title and body? I don't understand it at all the way it's written. For example, why would there be a dichotomy between "using the classpath" and "abusing auto modules"?

Comment: The classpath (i.e. unnamed module) remains primarily so that legacy code will still work as before. It would be crazy to ask the massive Java community to deal with the modulepath/automatic modules as a breaking change.

Comment: I can update the question. @user3305489: I guess you're asking why Java 9 does not simply turn all JARs on the class path into automatic modules?

Comment: Finally, I found the edit functionality :D

Comment: And now you have a name, too! Welcome to StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are at least two reasons:

- Just as regular modules, automatic ones are suspect to certain examinations by the module system, e.g. [not splitting packages](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/#Split-Packages). Since JARs on the class path can (and occasionally do) split packages, imposing that check on them would be backwards-incompatible and break a number of applications.
- The unnamed module can read all platform modules, whereas automatic modules can only read those that made it into the module graph. That means a JAR needing the *java.desktop* module (for example) will work from the class path but not from the module graph unless *java.desktop* also makes it into the graph (via a dependency or `--add-modules`).

I have no time right now to check the second but that's what [the State of the Module system](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#automatic-modules) says:

> After a module graph is resolved, therefore, an automatic module is made to read every other named module, whether automatic or explicit

Resolution works on the declared dependencies and an automatic modules declares none.

Comment: That leads me back to the same question that I already wrote in another thread. I repeat it: Alex Buckley told us at devoxxUS (Modular Development with JDK 9) automatic modules: "... Requires everything, they require each other, they require all modules in the jdk image and they require all of your modules as well, and they export their packages..." (The quote is similar what he said). Does it not mean java.desktop is accessible inside the automatic module-a when its need this dependency?

Comment: Maybe he said "reads" instead of "requires"? Anyways, I updated my answer.

Comment: He said "requires" youtu.be/rfOjch4p0Po?t=31m But the behavior that I can see is what you mean. The automatic-modules declare nothing, but they are ready to use dependencies from the module graph when those were added by an explicit module.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the items listed in the accepted answer, there is one more difference: unnamed modules can access all packages of modules that come with Java, even is they are not exported. 
As long the class is public, access will work - the same as before Java 9. But as soon as a jar is run from module path, it will be able to access only exported packages.

For example if some `.jar` has this code:

```
com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ArrayQueue c = new com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ArrayQueue(10);
```

it will run normally without any warnings when placed on class path, but when run from module path (as automatic module) it will fail at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class test1.C 
(in module test1) cannot access class com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ArrayQueue 
(in module java.management) because module java.management does not export 
com.sun.jmx.remote.internal to module test1
```

Note that this is different from the well known illegal reflective access warning, which is about using reflection to access private fields or methods. Here we are statically (non-reflectively) accessing public class (but from non-exported package).