# intellij java-9 build path- module path settings

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-9, module-path

i know intellij supports java9,and i know how to set classpath on intellij by adding libraries to build path.

but how does it works in java 9, is there a section for module path in intellij?

i think java 9 uses classpath if it cannot find classes on module path. so should both  classpath and module-path exist on intellij settings ?

and one last question, when i add a jar to libraries(java8 jar),  is it  an unnamed module or when it will be a automatic module?

Comment: It's just a matter of installing and opening IntelliJ project settings, isn't it?  When you add a jar depending on *where it is resolved*, on modulepath or the classpath its either treated as automatic or unnamed respectively.

Comment: no it is not. if it was i wouldnot asking that question. isn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDEA currently uses a heuristic to decide wheather or not to put the whole project on the module path, see [How to run Java 9 application with classpath rather than module path in IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370986) for details